# React: this.setState() working in some functions, not in others within the same component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop a simple little survey component with its own local state.  I've already successfully used this.setState() in my handleChange function to update which radio button is selected.  I can see that it's working in console logs and on the live page.  However, I am now trying to use the state to display a modal and highlight incomplete questions if the user tries to submit the survey without completing it.  The functions I have to do this execute, but the state does not update.  I am having trouble seeing any difference between where I updated state successfully and where I didn't.

Here's my container where I'm controlling state and defining the functions.  I don't *think* any other code is relevant, but let me know if I need to include something else:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { history } from '../history'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import _ from 'lodash'
import { postPhq, sumPhq } from '../store'
import { Phq } from '.'
import { UnfinishedModal } from '.'

/**
 * CONTAINER
 */

class PhqContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      phq: {
        q1: false, q2: false, q3: false, q4: false, q5: false,
        q6: false, q7: false, q8: false, q9: false, q10: false
      },
      hilitRows: [],
      modalOpen: false
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.makeButtons = this.makeButtons.bind(this)
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this)
  }

  //handles clicks on radio buttons
  handleChange(question, event) {
    var newPhq = this.state.phq
    newPhq[question] = event.target.value
    this.setState({phq: newPhq})
    console.log("radio button", this.state)
  }

  // on submit, first check that PHQ-9 is entirely completed
  // then score the PHQ-9 and dispatch the result to the store
  // as well as posting the results to the database and 
  // dispatching them to the store
  // if the PHQ-9 is not complete, open a modal to alert the user

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (this.checkCompletion()) {
      this.props.sumPhq(this.sum())
      this.props.postPhq(this.state.phq)
      this.props.history.push('/results')
    } else {
      console.log(this.unfinishedRows())
      this.toggleModal()
      this.setState({hilitRows: this.unfinishedRows()})
    }
  }

  // returns true if user has completed the PHQ-9 with no missing values
  checkCompletion() {
    return !this.unfinishedRows().length || this.oneToNine().every(val => val === 0)
  }

  unfinishedRows() {
    return Object.keys(_.pickBy(this.state.phq, (val) => val === false))
  }

  oneToNine() {
    var qs1to9 = Object.assign({}, this.state.phq)
    delete qs1to9.q10
    return Object.values(qs1to9)
  }

  toggleModal() {
    console.log("I'm about to toggle the modal", this.state)
    this.setState({modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen})
    console.log("I toggled the modal", this.state)
  }

  // scores the PHQ-9
  sum() {
    return this.oneToNine
      .map(val => parseInt(val))
      .reduce((total, num) => total + num)
  }

  makeButtons = (num, labels) => {
    var question = 'q' + (num + 1).toString()
    return (
      <div style={rowStyle}>
        {labels.map((label, i) => {
          return (
            <td style={{border: 'none'}}>
              <div className="col radio center-text" >
                <input type="radio"
                  value={i}
                  onChange={(event) => {this.handleChange(question, event)}}
                  checked={this.state.phq[question] && parseInt(this.state.phq[question]) == i} />
                <label>{label}</label>
              </div>
            </td>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Phq {...this.state} {...this.props}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          makeButtons={this.makeButtons} />
        <UnfinishedModal show={this.state.modalOpen} toggleModal={this.toggleModal} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    postPhq: (qs) => {
      dispatch(postPhq(qs))
    },
    sumPhq: (total) => {
      dispatch(sumPhq(total))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(() => { return {} }, mapDispatch)(PhqContainer)

const rowStyle = {
  paddingRight: 15,
  borderWidth: 0,
  margin: 0,
  border: 'none',
  borderTop: 0
}
```

This line `this.setState({phq: newPhq})` updates the state.  This line `this.setState({hilitRows: this.unfinishedRows()})` and this line  `this.setState({modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen})` do not.

Comment: Which method?  toggleModal is bound to this.  So is handleSubmit.  Can you be more explicit?

Comment: While there might be other issues, you should know that `setState` is asynchronous, so doing a console log afterwards is not guaranteed to reflect changes.  However, `setState` accepts a callback as it's second argument if you want to put a console.log there.

Comment: sorry didnt see you bound everything in the constructor...dont see that very often. can you post the code for your `Phq` component

Comment: @gravityplanx thank you!  My code isn't working for other reasons but you're right, state is being set.  I didn't know setState was asynchronous.  A console log in a callback function shows the change.

Comment: Katie could you please post what your `Phq` component looks like? Also is there a reason that you are passing it your entire state and props? You should ideally only pass state/props that you need to the child component.

Comment: @HLe the reason I didn't post my `Phq` component is because my question was resolved, essentially (see previous comments).  But there is no good reason for passing all my state and props -- I was just copying from other code; thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue happen in my project like setState is not working in some functions but its perfect for other functions in the same component. First of all you should understand, As mentioned in the React documentation, the setState being fired synchronously. So you can check like below value being updated.

```
this.setState({mykey: myValue}, () =>  {
    console.log(this.state.mykey);
});
```

In my case, I was tried to update the value of an event onChange with an input, in every keyUp it's trying to update, Its causes the problem for me. So I have tried to used a debounce(delay) for the function so its working fine for me. Hope this hint will help you or someone else.

```
this.myFunction = debounce(this.myFunction,750);
<Input onChange={this.myFunction} />
```